# C++: Can I put a child object into an array of parent objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, parent-child

Say I have an class called 'Tile'

```
class Tile 
{
    private:
        int x, y;
};
```

And a class called 'Door' that extends 'Tile'

```
class Door : Tile
{
    private:
        bool open;
};
```

Can I make an array of Tile objects, for instance to create a room, and then have a Door object in the same array since it is an extension of Tile? If not are there any alternatives that I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I put a child object into an array of parent objects?

No.

An object of type `T` is always of type `T`, never another type, even if that type is related. Arrays always contain objects of one single type.

> If not are there any alternatives that I could use to accomplish this?

Reference `T&` and pointer `T*` can refer to an object whose type is derived from `T`. You cannot store references in an array though. So, you may use an array of pointers.

Perhaps the simplest and most flexible choice is an array of shared pointers:

```
std::shared_ptr<Tile> tiles[10];
```